# Using a SELECT Statement in the WHERE IN Clause i.e. WHERE blah in (SELECT b...)

Tags: sql-server-2005, pivot

I am trying to do some complex pivot query... and I need to do a select in the IN Clause...

[Example of the Pivot](https://web.archive.org/web/20191230182030/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/lorint/archive/2006/08/04/87166.aspx)

Looking at the Example in the above link, you can see they use the employee ids explicitly in their pivot. I would like to be able to do select instead of specifying the employee ids.

The only way I can think of doing it now, is by creating my pivot query in a string and using manipulation in a Stored Prodcedure to build the employee ids into a string, insert that into my PIVOT clause, and execute the resulting SQL....

Anyone think of a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pretty much have to use dynamic SQL when construction pivot queries when the pivot column contents cannot be hard coded.

Comment: Thanks rbobby, I had thought this might be the case, I was just wondering if there was some kind of funky array data type I could use... but I guess not